# Epic does not always imply surjective?

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

I'm asking about one type of proof of epic $\implies$ surjective like Clive Newstead's answer in [Epic implies Surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265092/907619) or Thomas Andrew's answer in [Morphism epimorphism if and only if surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691793/907619). For reference, here is the definition of epic that I'll be using (the same definition as in the first linked post):

A function $f \colon A \to B$ is epic if for all $Z$ and all $\alpha, \alpha^{\prime} \colon B \to Z$, $\alpha \circ f = \alpha^{\prime} \circ f \implies \alpha = \alpha^{\prime}$.

Now, I can understand why the proofs work in sets $Z$ with at least two distinct elements. But if $Z$ has one element, no matter the set $B$ we have $\alpha = \alpha^{\prime}$ and the implication $\alpha \circ f = \alpha^{\prime} \circ f \implies \alpha = \alpha^{\prime}$ holds trivially. Then the choice of $Z$ necessarily means that $f$ is epic, but $f$ need not be surjective: for example we can have $B = \{0, 1\}$, $Z = \{1\}$, and $\forall x \in A$, $f(x) = 0$.  So why do the proofs in the linked posts assume that $Z$ has at least two distinct elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition requires the implication to hold for **every** $Z$. It is exactly because of your observation (i.e. the implication always hold when $|Z|=1$) that we only need to prove the implication holds for $|Z|>1$ when proving $f$ is epic.

Comment: Ah, of course I misread the definition. Thanks for the help!